# Softlayer Evault Price Ids

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create an evault backup programmatically using soflayer API. I have everything I need except for how to obtain the price id for the evault backup size we need. How can I do that dynamically, or if its not available, just the list of price ids for evault storage sizes?

Ive already looked in documentation and also contacted support which they suggested SO with Softlayer tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick view, perhaps using an object filter through the server's datacenter could work:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[categories, pricingLocationGroup[locations]]&objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"evault"}}, "pricingLocationGroup":{"locations":{"name":{"operation":"sao01"}}}}}

Method: Get
```

Replace: "sao01" with the server's datacenter name that you wish to order an evault. In case that it doesn't return any response

> **Updated**

My apologies, we should know that the prices are based on the locations, see the below article to get more information about it:

- [Location-based Pricing and
  You](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you)

The below rest request, will help you to get **standard prices** for datacenters based on these kind of prices:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[categories, pricingLocationGroup[locations]]&objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"evault"}}, "locationGroupId":{"operation":"is null"}}}

Method: Get
```

Also, I can provide a rest request to identify which datacenter is based on standard or location prices:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters?objectMask=mask[priceGroups]

Method: Get
```

The **standard prices** should be applied for the **datacenters which don't have "priceGroups"** property/information, for the other datacenters (which have priceGroups), you should use the first request that I provided.

Comment: So the price ids for the evault storage options the same across all environments correct? (dedicated vs public)

Comment: Yes, the prices are the same, they just change according to the datacenter in which the server resides.

Comment: The example you posted returned data as expected. However when I put in many other datacenter codes (e.g. dal09) for the last parameter in that request (operation:xxx) , it did not return any data. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true. the **dal09** datacenter is based on standard prices, please see **Updated** section in my answer to get more information

Comment: My apologies for the incomplete information, please let me know any question or doubt

Comment: Thanks for the update. So it seems after I made the last call you provided and the article you posted, that the ones with price groups were all outside the US. One other quick confirmation; So the actual price ids for each storage option is the same across data centers unless it has the priceGroups data correct?

Comment: Yes, if the datacenter has priceGroups, you should applied the first request that I provided (in which you send the datacenter name), because the price could vary for each datacenter